# intersection of 2 vectors in homogenous space

Tags: vectors, projective-geometry

This is a homework question but i would just like to clarify my solution

Given a vector

$$L_1: (1, 1, 2) + x(1, 4, 1)$$
 $$L_2: (2, 2, 3) + y(1, 4, 1)$$

Finding the intersection of these $2$ lines in projective geometry will result in cross product of

$$L_1 \times L_2$$

Hence, the solution would be

$$(1, 0, 0) + z(0, 0, 0)$$

Am I right to say this?

Thanks.

Comment: It’s not clear which space(s) you’re working with in your question, and it appears that you’re mixing them up. If the two lines are in $\mathbb P^2$, they’re not parallel and have a finite intersection point. You can find that via a cross product, but not in the way you’re going about it. If, on the other hand, the lines are in $\mathbb R^3$, then when you switch to homogeneous coordinates you’re working with vectors that have *four* components, not three, for which a cross product is not defined.

Comment: @amd hi. The point is in r3 space

Comment: In that case, the second part of my comment applies: there is no cross product defined for a pair of four-tuples.

Comment: How about it not being a homogenous equation? The question states that this is a real world coordinate and it will map into a image based coordinate via a camera